# What is the correct way to phrase to keep their motivation going?

Tags: expression-choice

To keep their motivation going or "...their motivation on going? Which is the correct way to say it?

Answer (score 1):

Given that motivation is essentially an emotional state, it does not "go", so "go' should go. A cleaner option is "to keep them motivated" rather than either of the original options.

Comment: Who wrote this anonymous comment? A bot?